# Replacing the Close icon for a JQueryUI Dialog box

Tags: css, jquery-ui, icons, jquery-ui-dialog

After extensive searching on this topic, I haven't been able to find an answer, so hopefully someone can help me with this issue.  I have a relatively basic dialog box:

```
$("#dialog-search").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:dimensionData.height,
    width: dimensionData.width,
    modal: true,
    title: dimensionData.title,
    position: [x,y],
    open: function() {
        $("#dialog-search .dateField").blur();
    },
    close: function(event, ui){
       callBack(event,ui);
    }
});
```

What I want to do is replace the X icon (ui-icon-close) with a different icon provided by the ui (ui-icon-minus), so that clicking the minus icon closes the dialog instead.  I've seen posts on how to hide the icon or replace it with a custom image in css, but I haven't yet found a way to replace the icon with another icon to perform the same functionality.

Edit: I also want to be able to use ui-icon-close for a different functionality in my dialog box by adding a custom behavior/location, but that may be outside the scope for this question.  Feel free to address this if it's a related solution, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to see the structure of the dialog and it should not be hard to do it.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#theming

Use the `create` event to change the class of the close button icon to class of another icon will do.

http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/kHU2M/1/

```
$("#dialog-search").dialog({
    create: function(event, ui) { 
      var widget = $(this).dialog("widget");
      $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close span", widget)
          .removeClass("ui-icon-closethick")
          .addClass("ui-icon-minusthick");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out.  It's really frustrating that javascript is so obtuse that you have to remove and add a Class just to accomplish a simple image replacement.

Comment: But how do I add my own image? To just create a CSS-class that uses background-image:... doesnt really work, it just messes the whole thing up. Is there a tutorial for exchanging the X with something else completely, not one of the "built in" images? And preferrably larger.

Comment: @Ted I have added one more answer with custom image.

Answer (score 12):

Old question, but maybe I'll help someone. Following `CSS` made the trick for me, totally custom `Close` button UI. Not very elegant :), but works fine for me.

```
.ui-icon-closethick {
    background-image: url(images/my-10px-image.png) !important;
    background-position: left top !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close, .ui-icon-closethick {
    width: 10px !important;
    height: 10px !important;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close, .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

My custom close button shown below:

[image]