# DropDown Menu not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown menu, and add 'ok' and 'cancel buttons.
I have the code:

```js
  $("#dialog").hide();
  $("#target").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").show();
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="target" value="click" />
</body>

</html>
```

I want to be able to click on the Button, and it should open a window with a dropdown menu with the ability to select one of the options, and an ok and cancel button.

However, this seems to display the button and the menu at the same time (no popup), and I'm also not sure on how to add ok, and cancel buttons to it, any ideas?

I've tried using an onclick mechanisms in the html code and then actually using a function int the javascript portion, but that doesn't really help.

Comment: Did you actually include jQuery library which you seem to be using?

Comment: @ererer Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: The closure of your `<button>`element is not at the right place. Must be `<button class="button">Button</button>`

Comment: I've Updated the code.

Comment: Including the JQuery library doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the [dialog documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close).
Take a look, there are all methods and options to custom your own `.dialog`

```js
  $("#dialog").hide();
  $("#target").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").show();
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  });

  $('#formBrands').submit(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog('close');
  });
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #52B3D9;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <form id="formBrands" method="post" action="yourPHP.php">
      <select name="brands">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="OK" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="target" value="click" />
```

Comment: Hi Sorry I've removed the original CSS button, I only wanted to have a click button which opens a popup window with ok and close button

Comment: I need an Ok and Cancel button as Pressing OK let's me send the <option> to php, you're answer has no Ok button/popup.

Comment: I add a `<form>`wrapper to send to your PHP page the `brands` value (your select)

Comment: Okay Thanks Robiseb, and finnaly, how would I close the popup when pressing ok (and saving the value)? Something like window.close?

Comment: Answer updated with the documentation of jquery UI dialog. I add a listener on the submit form to close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I add 3 things to your code and it works for me.

1. jQuery library.
2. jQuery UI library.
3. Wrap the javascript code in the `$(document).ready()`.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="target" value="click" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").hide();
  $("#target").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").show();
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  });
});
```

You can check the running version on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnhTriet/2aax0qaq/).

Comment: Is there a way to change the name of the close button to be "Cancel"?

Comment: Yes, please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909157/replacing-the-close-icon-for-a-jqueryui-dialog-box).